# How to force int to string in Laravel JSON?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I've recently updated my server to a newer version of MySQL and PHP 7 for various reasons. On my previous instance, running PHP 5.5, Laravel's `response()->json()` always converted `tinyint`'s into a string. Now running newer server software, it's returning me `int`'s -as it should...

I'd have to change a lots of my codebase to either cast types / convert them into a string manually, whic I'm trying to avoid at the moment.

Is there a way to somehow force `response()->json()` to return `int`'s as `string`'s?

Comment: PHP is very loose about types so even its int you can use as string except  if you are using `===`.

Comment: you did not understand the question I am afraid

Comment: I don't really know Laravel, but could it be possible to override the native `json()` function and use `settype()` in it ? This way you won't have to change all your function calls.

Comment: Yes, I'll look into the method and try to override it. Thanks.

Comment: there are a workaround to do this, `jsonp`

Comment: In you mode write the following line
 protected $casts = [ 'id' => 'string' ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is there a way to somehow force response()->json() to return int's as string's
>
> I don't want to change the code base - do not want to cast types, convert it,

No. There's no option for that. You need to do that yourself if needed.

Comment: Maybe with some MySQL / PHP reconfiguration, maybe/hopefully? :(

Comment: No. There's no switch for that. It makes no sense. Not sure what you need that behavior for too

Comment: The app where I'm expiriencing this is an API, and it's used by a mobile (iOS / Android) application which handles everything as string, not since Swift and Java are both strict-typed langies, this is causing a crash on both of them...

Comment: Fix the app then. Not sure how exactly you parse the JSON in apps, but it smells like it's simply done wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to cast integer into string in laravel

in your model you can cast id to string. Its as follows

```
protected $casts = [ 'id' => 'string' ];
```

But the downside is that you would have to do that for all Models.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify a lot of code you could run response data through a quick and dirty function. Instead of going directory to JSON you should instead grab the data as a nested array. Then put it through a function like this:

```
function convertIntToString ($myArray) {
    foreach ($myArray as $thisKey => $thisValue) {
        if (is_array($thisValue)) {
            // recurse to handle a nested array
            $myArray[$thisKey] = convertIntToString($thisValue);
        } elseif (is_integer($thisValue)) {
            // convert any integers to a string
            $myArray[$thisKey] = (string) $thisValue;
        }
    }
    return $myArray;
}
```

The function will convert integers to strings and use recursion to handle nested arrays. Take the output from that and then convert it to JSON.

Comment: I wrote quite a similar recursive function as you did... but I'll avoid that for now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is to to use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) and 
[Fractal transformers](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal)

Fractal transformers are extremely useful when you have complex responses with multiple relations included.

Answer (score -1):

You can typecast it to string:

return response->json(["data" => (string)1]);

Comment: As I said - I don't want to change the code base - do not want to cast types, convert it, etc...